# "dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration" after do-release-upgrade to 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, keyboard

I've executed `sudo do-release-upgrade` from a 16.04.3 LTS and now:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.postinst: line 103: 
/etc/default/keyboard: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm completely stuck, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was having `/etc/default/keyboard` not writable.
Permissions where ok

```
$ ls -l /etc/default/keyboard                            
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 88 feb 27 23:05 /etc/default/keyboard
```

but file attributes where wrong:

```
$ lsattr /etc/default/keyboard
----i--------e-- /etc/default/keyboard
```

The (i) attrb [means *immutable*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chattr.1.html). 
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr.

Solution:

```
$ chattr -i /etc/default/keyboard
$ apt remove keyboard-configuration
$ apt install keyboard-configuration
$ apt upgrade
```